# Border-radius on ie9 - works locally but not when deployed

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-7, css

As the titles says, my css works fine locally when using ie9, but when deployed to IIS7 the border-radius and box-shadow is not applied, although works fine with ff4 and Chrome.

```
.blabla
{
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    height: 101px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 225px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:url('./Content/images/background.png') scroll 0 0px no-repeat;
}
```

I'm working with an MVC3 project, which has the `<!DOCTYPE html>` already in. It did not work locally originally when using `border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;` I changes it to only mention 10px once and that made the trick (and also made the box-shadow working) but it's still not working when deployed. Any ideas?

Edit: I checked in IE's developers tool, the border-radius is there locally but does not show up when deployed, which explains why it's not working... the question is why is it not displayed?

EDIT2: I noticed something else... My doctype while written correctly in my code:  `<!DOCTYPE html>` is shown as disabled in the browser: `<!-- DOCTYPE html -->` Still can't figure how to fix it.

EDIT3: I created a normal ASPX Web Application, same issue. Works locally but on IIS7 the doctype is commented...

Comment: Wow, that's really, really strange, converting a doctype to a comment. Maybe because of some validation issues in Visual Studio? I'm not sure if it helps, but [there's an HTML5 validation/IntelliSense plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d/) for VS.

Comment: The wierd thing is that the doctype is not commented when running it locally on ie9, only does it when deployed... I tried changing it to the good old `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">` and it does the exact same thing... Oo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your page probably triggers IE7 mode in IE9. On your local machine you manually changed the settings to use standard mode in IE9, but after deployment you again see the page in IE7 mode => no border-radius. Been there, done that.

Another reason might be the content type your server sends for the page, see http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: I've noticed that when I check the developers tool in ie9, the Document Mode is set to IE7 standards and Browser Mode to IE9 Compat View. If I change either of them to IE9 it works fine. But everything I've found online that's supposed to affect this doesn't.

Comment: Solution found! The meta tag needs to specify EmulateIE9 and not just 9 or IE9: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`

Comment: Thank you LanFeusT, this was the only way I could get it working too.

Answer (score 7):

I was struggling with the same issue. *But I just found my answer.* It was IE's "Compatibly View".

Show Command Bar > Page > Compatibility View Settings.

For my particular issue, it was a defaulted check box "Display intranet sites in Compatibly View".

Comment: Thank you! That's been driving me up the wall for the last hour.

Comment: Took OVER AN HOUR before I found this... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Hey, not sure why that is happening, it shouldn't normally. Have you tried the easy stuff like refreshing without cache?

Anyway, you should use all vendor prefixes:

```
.blabla {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000000;
}
```

Comment: yeah I am using them all already just forgot to remove the -moz-border one to make the post smaller :) I've added the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` tag to my page as well but that made no difference.

Comment: It's very strange and I'm sure it's something that is not related to code. HTML and CSS are client side so regardless of server they should be the same. There are rare cases in which server configuration can affect them, but I don't see how this applies here. Do you have any config files (like .htaccess for Apache) that override some headers or such?

Comment: Can you post a link to take a look with various browsers pleas?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's an internal website. I've tried with all major browsers though and it all works fine but IE9 (well... I actually have a listing bug with Safari displaying them inline but the corners and shadows are there). I noticed that the same website running on IE8 while the css3 isn't supposed to work anyway it also comments out the Doctype as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The meta tag worked for me.  I had to put it in the HeadContent section on the page though, putting in the masterpage did not fix it.  Since I don't want to have to worry about compatibility mode setting on the client side, forcing it for me works better.